# Understanding the Behavior of std::end() and Memory Allocation in Vectors

Tags: c++, oop, vector, stl, iterator

What exactly does `std::end()` point to? When using a `std::vector`, does it allocate extra memory to accommodate the end position of the elements?

Comment: `std::end(v)` points to a non-existing element immediately after the last real element of `v`. Normally no extra memory is allocated for this fictitious element. The programmer is not allowed to dereference the end iterator so there is no need for it to be backed by memory.

Answer (score 4):

Calling [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) on a `std::vector` simply returns the vector's [`end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) iterator, which points at the memory address *beyond* the last element of the vector's array:

[image]

If the `vector`'s [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is less than its [`capacity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), there will be memory allocated for this 1-past-the-end position, but regardless, the content of the end position is undefined and should *never* be accessed.